# assign canvas to div, adapt canvas dimensions to div dimenson - how to fix?

Tags: javascript, html, css, canvas

I have this example of a canvas as a div background (I forked it from another example, don't remember where I found it):
http://jsfiddle.net/sevku/6jace59t/18/

```
var canvas = document.getElementsByTagName('canvas')[0];
var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
var divHeight = document.getElementById('canvas').clientHeight;
var divWidth = document.getElementById('canvas').clientWidth;

function assignToDiv(){ // this kind of function you are looking for
  dataUrl = canvas.toDataURL();
  document.getElementsByTagName('div')[0].style.background='url('+dataUrl+')'
}

function draw() { // replace with your logic
  ctx.fillStyle = "rgb(100, 250, 100)";
  ctx.fillRect (10, 10, divWidth-20, divHeight-20);
}

draw()
assignToDiv()
```

My problem; If I put the dimensions of the div 300 x 150, the canvas does what it is supposed to do. But if I change the dimensions, the canvas is supposed to adapt to the div dimensions. What did I do wrong that this doesn't happen?

PS: I'm a beginner, so please forgive me stupid questions.

Comment: Do you mean you want to enlarge the canvas to fit the `div`'s dimension? Is the `background-repeat:repeat-x;` is what you want? For example, if the div is `600 x 300` now, what you want the canvas to display?

Comment: Thanks for your comment.
I don't want to repeat the background.
I want the canvas which I use to automatically adapt to the div dimensions. So if I change for example the height of the div to 600, the canvas should automatically become 600 as well.
I tried to solve this with divHeight and divWidth but that did not quite work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because if you don't give [canvas](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/canvas) `width` and `height`, it's default to `300x150`, so after you get the width and height from div, you should use them to set your `canvas`' dimensions as well.

Another point worth notice is that you use `div.style.background` property to set the background image, however, as there's many background related properties (e.g: `background-repeat` in your jsfiddle, `background-position`, `background-size`...), the `background` can set all of them at once. 
When you use `div.style.background='url('+dataUrl+')';`. It overrides all other background-related properties to `initial`.

If you want to preserve those properties, you may either reset them after you set `style.background`, or you can use `div.style.backgroundImage` to change the background image without affect other background related properties.

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6jace59t/22/)

```js
var canvas = document.getElementsByTagName('canvas')[0];
var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
var divHeight = document.getElementById('canvas').clientHeight;
var divWidth = document.getElementById('canvas').clientWidth;
   
// VVVV After you get WxH, set the canvas's dimension too.
canvas.width = divWidth;
canvas.height = divWidth;

var div1 = document.getElementById('canvas');
var div2 = document.getElementById('canvas2');

function assignToDiv(div){ // this kind of function you are looking for
  var dataUrl = canvas.toDataURL();
  div.style.background='url('+dataUrl+')';  // This line will overwrite your background settings.
  div.style.backgroundRepeat = 'repeat-x';  // Use this to set background related properties after above.
}

function assignToDivAlt(div){ // this kind of function you are looking for
  var dataUrl = canvas.toDataURL();
  div.style.backgroundImage = 'url('+dataUrl+')';  // Only set the background-image would have same effect.
}

function draw() { // replace with your logic
  ctx.fillStyle = "rgb(100, 250, 100)";

  // If you don't set WH, then the canvas would be 300x150, and those 
  // you drawed but out of boundary are clipped.
  ctx.fillRect (10, 10, divWidth-20, divHeight-20);
}

draw()
assignToDiv(div1);
assignToDiv(div2);
```

```css
canvas {display:none;}
div {
    width:600px;
    height:550px;
    border:1px solid grey;
    background-repeat:repeat-x;
}
```

```html
<canvas></canvas>
<div id="canvas"></div>
<div id="canvas2"></div>
```